# cifs utils - SMBmount to MS file cluster

Tags: windows, cluster, failover

i'm working at a company with many linux machines connected to a windows SMB share.

I'm migrating data to the a new (2019, but also on 2012r2) windows file cluster so we can have HA.

When triggering a failover (node 1 to 2, or vice-versa), while i'm copying some data to and from that mounted share, the copy gets interrupted (whereas the windows clients hold back and continue the filetransfer).

On some machines in our LAN, many machines start to struggle and need a a hard reset as the kernel locks up.

Unfortunately no info from this.

Any parameters i could feed to the utils?

Regards,

Martijn